# Encode video with ffmpeg using CUDA without NVENC

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, cuda

There's quite a bit of info about using hardware encoder built in Kepler-based and newer NVidia cards to encode video. As far as I understood all of them just pass the encoding to hardware encoder, without actually using CUDA.
What I am trying to achieve is to accelerate video encoding using plain old CUDA on old pre-Kepler hardware (GTX 570 here, Fermi).

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible. It's only via NVENC. See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro#CUDACUVIDNVDEC